# Input text is not working in jQuery template when click event is enabled on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, jquery-templates

I have a jQuery template in below structure.

```
<div class="parent-class">    
    <div class="sub-class"> 
        <div clas="sub-input-class">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here I've added a click event for parent Div `parent-class`:

```
$(".parent-class").click('some method')
```

When clicked on input text, input field is not focused. Not able to enter text in the text field.
Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: code please or no help is coming, trust me :)

Comment: updated with code. waitin fr answers :)

Comment: it MUST work. probably some piece of your code blocks it. do you have it somewhere online?

Comment: when i run in firefox browser, it works fine. when same code is run on iphone, the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this fiddle:

```
$(".parent-class").on('click',function(){alert('test');});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rwEPY/1/

It is working great for me if i do it this way.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: $(".parent-class").click is working fine. text field is not opening.